Can we bring Cobra Rum from Vietnam to India?
My friend recently went to Vietnam he wanted to get the Cobra rum as a souvenir but wasn't sure if it's legal and there wouldn't be any problem to get through the customs.

I am seriously doubtful that you will get it past Indian customs.

Presumably you are interested in the question of the dead snake in the bottle.  The general duty free allowances are Rs50000/15000 and up to 2 litres of wine or liquor (journeys from Nepal, Bhutan or Myanmar, or Pakistan may be treated differently)
